# django and jquery on click load object fields into div

Tags: jquery, django

I need a solution to this problem:

I have a django site that displays all recipes in a recipe list

each of these recipes is a link that when clicked should load the fields of that recipe into a popupdiv

so far I have the popup div all set - now i just need to figure out how to access the recipe fields of that button.

basically the content i would like to load is recipe.name recipe.author recipe.steps etc 
but i don't know how to.

Right now I also have a form being loaded into the div using ajax so I don't want to interfere in anyway with the ajax call (i will post this code as well). Would it make sense to also use ajax for a problem like this?

here is my button click function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".button").click(function(){
        var content = $("#popupContact").load($('#recipe'));
    });
});
```

here is the template for my page:

```
{% block content %}
{% autopaginate recipe_list 6 %}
    <div id="recipe_cont">
            {% for recipe in recipe_list %}
        <div class="recipe">
            <div class="button">//here is the button that is clicked to load recipe 
            <a href="{% url cookbook.views.userrecipe recipe.id %}" style="display: none;"></a>   
            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}chicknbraw.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70" style="display:inline;" />
            <h4>{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
             </div>
            <h5>{{ recipe.author }}</h5>
            <h5>Prep Time: {{ recipe.prep_time }} minutes</h5>

            <h6><a href="/addrecipe/{{ recipe.id }}">Add Recipe</a>
                <a href="/removerecipe/{{ recipe.id }}">Remove Recipe</a></h6>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div id="popupContact" class="popup">//load recipe information into this div
            <a id="popupContactClose" style="cursor:pointer;float:right;">x</a>
            <p id="contactArea">
            <h1 style="text-align:center">Create New Recipe</h1>
            {% include 'cookbook/create_form.html' %} //this is for the form that is loaded. Is there a way to include a different template? Maybe have multiple contactAreas and hide/show different ones depending on what is being loaded?
            </p>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup">
    </div>  
    <div id="col2-footer">
    {% paginate %}
    <p id="recipe_order_text"> order by: <a href="/userbook/ordered/name">abc</a>|<a href="/userbook/ordered/date">date</a> 
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

here is the form ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function hijack() {
        var form = $('form#createrecipeform');
        form.each (function(){
            this.reset();
            });
        form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('ajax form submission function called successfully.');
            //form = $(this);
            console.log(form)
            var serialized_form = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: serialized_form, 
                success: (function(data) { 
                    console.log('ajax success function called successfully.');
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if (data.success) {
                        console.log('success');
                    } else {        
                        console.log('failure');
                        var newForm = data.form;
                        form.replaceWith(newForm);
                        hijack();
                    }
                })
            });
            return false;
        });
    };

    hijack();

});
```

thanks a lot for any solutions you may have

katie

Comment: Do you create a form in your view? Do you have a form class with a template?

Comment: no i dont create a form in my view nor do i have a form class with a template(although i do for creating new recipes) I was hoping I could somehow just grab the recipe information since I am clicking on the button that contains that recipe already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a div that is hidden for each recipe that is loaded and then used .html() to place each of the divs wihtin the popup

this ended up working perfectly - better then replaceWith append or clone

thank you for your help @akhaku

Answer (score 1):

A hack-y way to do it (not recommended!) would be something like the following (in javascript)

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var recipe = $(this).parent();
    var name   = $('h4', recipe);
    var author = $('h5', recipe);
    // etc etc
});
```

To make this a *little* bit better, assign classes to the elements containing the name and author, then you can do the following instead of getting the h4 and h5

```
var name = $('.recipe-name', recipe);
```

Again this is very much a hack, and should be done differently...

Comment: what about using ajax - would that make more sense?

Comment: Isn't the form already loaded via ajax? You don't need to ajax this specific part since it's already in the DOM, ajax is used to GET more data into the DOM or POST data to the server. Are you asking how to get this info into the form?

Comment: well i guess my problem is that I also have comments and add comment within my recipe so I would need to load a page that has the recipe information and all comments and then the ability to add a comment